# iOS: Tableview cells made in autolayout don't load until scrolled to

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

For some reason the  cells I have made using autolayout do not properly show until they are scrolled to.
The best way I can show this is with an animation of what is happening so here:

http://postimg.org/image/ohpq08ubf/

The cells are already allocated so I think the problem has more to do with the actual view trying to not show itself & calculate its constraints and such until it needs to.

How can I make sure the cells are totally and fully loaded + displayed so that I can have a smooth scrolling experience?

Comment: Is there anything loading which is very slow? Or maybe you are refreshing the UI on a background thread. Is the size of the table view correct?

Comment: Since the cells are made using autolayout, the height required for each cell cannot be figured out until autolayout has done its thing and displayed itself. Once it has done so, I change the height required for the table. Even if I put in some huge height (more than needed for the cells), the cells do not attempt to layout until I scroll to them.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe you shouldn't use autolayout. What does Apple say about autolayout in table view cells? Maybe this isn't supported.

Comment: I don't think it is directly supported... however I've built basically my entire project in autolayout and I don't even know where to begin changing everything to springs and struts. Also, I feel like using springs and struts would make it very difficult and tedious to handle views with dynamic content... and pretty much every view I have involves dynamic content. So, are there any tricks I could use to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I have build an App.net client and I calculate the size of the table view cells using the `sizeWithFont` method of NSString.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be expected behavior (UITableView loads cells only when they come into view). This is part of why scrolling through a UITableView with tons of entries is so smooth, it recycles (dequeues) the cells.

Looking at the animation it's tough to see what the problem is. Is the problem that the white rounded rect background appearing on top of the gray background while it's in view? This could be aided by having the default cell configuration be the white rounded rect (visible) atop the gray background. This would mean that it would be there when scrolling into view and only the textual data displayed on top of the white rounded rect would be rendered as cells come into view.

Comment: I don't think so. Even if the white background is loaded completely this should be faster.

Comment: Is part of the issue that the scrolling is jittery? Or is it just that the cells are displayed a fraction of a second after they move into view?

Comment: I'm talking about the display delay.

Comment: I replaced the gif with a more complete animation. The delay occurs only when scrolling to a cell for the first time it needs to be displayed. Once it has been displayed, scrolling through all the cells is smooth and there is no problem. It's not that it's jittery, I think it's just the low fps of the gif that makes it look that way.